# How to Display Dynamic Content below every article?

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

I am a new developer to Joomla. I am developing a website in which users will be able to write review for the articles. So, here I need to display a review form below every article. How can I achieve this? I have seen some extensions like custom properties which will place content below every article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. What I needed was a plugin to display content after every article.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use an extension that was specifically built for reviews.

There are [multiple options](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews) available in the Joomla Extensions Directory.